# postgreSQL with SQL Workbench: class java.time.LocalDate from date not supported

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, sql-workbench-j

I'm using SQL Workbench to access a postgreSQL database.
I downloaded the required plugins and java... But whenever I run a query with a column that contains a date, I get this error message:

`Conversion to class java.time.LocalDate from date not supported`

See the screenshot:
[screenshot about the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JKPa.png)

It seems to be a timezone related issue but apart from that I can't get any further -- and when I go through documentations, I find no references to this type of error.

Could you please show me the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What is your SQL Workbench/J build? Which JDBC driver version are you using? And which Java version?

Comment: which postgresql jdbc driver did you choosed?
you can try lower version like postgresql-42.0.0.jar

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm using the driver: `postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar` and sql workbench `Build 127 (2020-08-22 22:34`.